# What's causing "export 'default' (imported as 'Axios') was not found in 'axios' (module has no exports)"?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, axios

I'm using Ionic with VueJs and JSON-Server. I'm calling a get request with an OnMounted, but when I run Ionic Serve I get the following error:

```
export 'default' (imported as 'Axios') was not found in 'axios' (module has no exports)
```

It still compiles, and when I click the page where the OnMounted is, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at eval (index.js?f8df:1:1)
    at ./node_modules/axios/index.js (src_views_EventsPage_vue.js:277:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:233:33)
    at fn (app.js:486:21)
    at eval (AxiosService.js:5:63)
    at ./src/services/AxiosService.js (src_views_EventsPage_vue.js:73:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:233:33)
    at fn (app.js:486:21)
    at eval (EventsService.js:12:71)
    at ./src/services/EventsService.js (src_views_EventsPage_vue.js:84:1)
```

From what I can tell, the Axios `index.d.ts` file is as it should be, containing many exports. I've run `npm i axios --save.`

I use the same code in another project that does not run Ionic but has Vite and a few other things included.

Comment: Which version of Axios are you using? Can you show your `import` statement from Axios?

Comment: From the package.json:
    "axios": "^1.2.1"

Answer (score 2):

You are importing axios this way:

```
import { Axios } from "axios";
```

Try importing this way:

```
import axios from "axios";
```

(without the brackets)